# "Invalid configuration object" after creating a package.json using "npm init"

Tags: json, node.js, webpack

I had a running webpack configuration. But after using `npm init` to create the following package.json file:

```
{


 "name": "y",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.24.0",
    "babel-loader": "^6.4.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.23.0",
    "jshint": "^2.9.4",
    "jshint-loader": "^0.8.4",
    "node-libs-browser": "^2.0.0",
    "webpack": "^2.2.1"
  }
}
```

and installing the following modules:

```
npm install babel-core babel-loader jshint jshint-loader node-libs-browser  
babel-preset-es2015 babel-preset-react webpack  --save-dev
```

I got the error message

> Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using a configuration
>    object that does not match the API schema.
>    - configuration.resolve.extensions[0] should not be empty.

When I tried to restart the dev-server using

`webpack-dev-server`

The webpack.config.json looks like this:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: ["./global.js", "./app.js"],
  output: {
    filename: "bundle.js"
  },
  module: {
   loaders: [
     {
       test: /\.es6$/,
       exclude: /node_modules/,
       loader: 'babel-loader',
       query: {
         presets: ['react', 'es2015']
       }
     }
   ]
 },
 resolve: {
   extensions: ['', '.js', '.es6']
 },
}
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: Can you add your `webpack.config.js` to the question?

Comment: Done. See updated version.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [After upgrade to Webpack beta 23 I can no longer use blank extensions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39633754/after-upgrade-to-webpack-beta-23-i-can-no-longer-use-blank-extensions) - I believe that while recreating your `package.json`, you've ended up on a higher version of Webpack, meaning that your config no longer works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You installed the latest version of webpack with:

```
npm install --save-dev webpack
```

Webpack 2 does not allow an empty string in [`resolve.extensions`](https://webpack.js.org/guides/migrating/#resolve-extensions) anymore. Simply remove the empty string from the array of extensions:

```
resolve: {
  extensions: ['.js', '.es6']
},
```

You should also read the official [Migration Guide](https://webpack.js.org/guides/migrating/).